# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm writing a real-time search functionality in Angular with RxJS. I'm getting some error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined.
I'm using Angular 7 and I have tried different code samples from StackOverfloew, but couldn't fix this issue.

app.Component.html

```html
<input type='text' class="form-control input-txt-start" placeholder="Search Domain Name" name="domainId" (keyup)='getSearchResults(searchTerm$.next($event.target.value))'>

<ul *ngIf="results">
    <li *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9">
        {{ result}}
    </li>
</ul>
<p *ngIf="error">
    {{error}}
</p>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchService } from 'src/app/services/search.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [SearchService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  results: Object;
  searchTerm$: any = new Subject();
  error: any;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnit() { }

  getSearchResults(search) {
    this.searchService.search(search).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.results = res;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.error = err.message;
    });
  }
}
```

search.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SearchService {
  public httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };

  baseUrl: String = `${environment.API_URL}/api/domainCharts`;
  queryUrl: String = '?search=';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(debounceTime(500)).pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).pipe(switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${this.queryUrl}${term}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: check if it is the correct way to use pipe..why are you using pipe multiple times?

Comment: RxJS pipe is used to combine functional operators into a chain.

Comment: I have changed it to `return terms.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged(), switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)));` but I'm still getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more than 1 thing that are not right with what you are asking.

First, you are passing a `Subject` and expecting an `Observable`. This is why you are getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Then, you are passing `Subject` as `term` (I assume you want to send search keyword).

You don't need a `Subject` in your situation. You can do it like this:

Template:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control input-txt-start" placeholder="Search Domain Name" name="domainId" (keyup)='getSearchResults($event)'>  <---- Send only $event here
```

Component:

```
getSearchResults(event) {
    this.searchService.search(event.target.value).subscribe((res) => { // <--- Get target value of event
      console.log(res);
      this.results = res;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.error = err.message;
    });
  }
}
```

Service:

```
search(term) {  // <--- Notice that the parameter name became term instead of terms

    // You can use of() method of RxJS
    // You need to import of with "import { of } from 'rxjs';"
    // You can chain you operators in pipe() method with commas

    return of(term).pipe(
       debounceTime(500),
       distinctUntilChanged(),
       switchMap(() => this.searchEntries(term) // <--- Notice that, this function has no parameter
     );
  }
```

Comment: When I changed as per your suggestion as below, 

`
search(term) {
    
    return terms.pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged(), switchMap(() => this.searchEntries(term)));
  }
`

1. In return statement, if it is terms, it says **Cannot find name 'terms'**
2. In return statement, if I change it to term, it says **TypeError: term.pipe is not a function**

Comment: Updated the answer. You could use `of()` method of `RxJS`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html

Comment: But this way, `distinctUntilChanged()` becomes meaningless as you create a new observable every time this function is fired. I think you need to move `debounce` and `distinctUntilChanged` to component file. Maybe you can use `fromEvent` of `RxJS` to achieve this: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html

Comment: Thanks a ton @Harun, it worked for me. I will try by moving debounce and distinctUntilChanged and using fromEvent of RxJS and let you know.